# Generalization of Jensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, jensen-inequality

Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a $\mathbb R^n$-valued random vector such that $E(|X_i|)<\infty$ for all $i$. Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function.

Jensen's inequality tells us that $E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n))$ exists (in $]-\infty,\infty]$) and that
$$E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \ge f(E(X_1),\dots,E(X_n)).$$

So if we replace each $X_i$ by its expectation $E(X_i)$ we get something smaller. Does this still hold if we substitute only some of the $X_i$ by their expectations?

**Question:** Does it hold that $E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \ge E(f(E(X_1),X_2\dots,X_n))$?

---

Here are my thoughts:

Using the conditional Jensen's inequality we get that
\begin{align*}
E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)) &= E(E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)|X_2,\dots,X_n))\\
                    &\ge E(f(E(X_1|X_2,\dots,X_n),X_2\dots,X_n))
\end{align*}
holds whenever $E(|X_1||X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is a.s. finite.

If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent it follows that
$$E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \ge E(f(E(X_1),X_2\dots,X_n))$$
and we can iterate this to get
$$E(f(E(X_1),X_2\dots,X_n)) \ge E(f(E(X_1),E(X_2),X_3\dots,X_n)),$$
etc.

But what if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are not independent?

Comment: convex functions are continuous and thus measurable

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm not sure if this is true. Consider a function defined on the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. Take a nonmeasurable set $B$ from the boundary of the circle (I am guessing this exists). Define a function to be 1 on $B$ and 0 on the rest of the circle. Then the function is convex but neither continuous nor measurable.

Comment: convex functions are continuous on the interior of the domain on which they are convex. you gave domain $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: Can't you just restrict to $n=2$? (i.e. if you prove it for $n=2$, you get it for $n \ge 3$)

Comment: Is that obvious? For fixed $n$ it suffices to show that any one variable can be replaced by its expectation. But how would it work if we increase $n$?

Comment: @Epiousios The question linked in your bio seems to have been deleted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X_1$ be any non-constant random variable, and let $X_2=-X_1$.

For $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$, we have

$Ef(X_1,X_2)=E((X_1+X_2)^2)=0$

and

$E(f(EX_1,X2))=E((EX_1+X_2)^2)=E((X_2-EX_2)^2)=Var(X_2)>0$.